# Jquery Mobile App not displaying certain images on Android

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a full Jquery Mobile app the currently builds and looks fine in multiple browsers. I am currently working on getting the version ported using phonegap for android. As it loads up on the phone, it has several images that are loaded depending on localStorage (I originally used cookies but found some android devices aren't too friendly with that). Now, almost all of these triggers load images fine, except the last page. A certain set of images won't load, and I get the error (when running in an emulator `Unknown chromium error: -6`. Others on the page use the same process and have no problem, and all the images are referred to locally. 
Why would this be happening and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in the android browser, under phonegap, file names are case-sensitive. So it wasn't able to load things with capital letters and such.

Comment: Assume that file names are case sensitive on the actual devices. This is true of iOS and Android but not of their simulators/emulators that run on your desktop. This bit of confusion has tripped up more than one person.